# How to list all auto-start services in archlinux?

Tags: archlinux, systemd

I am aware of using systemctl status  to check a particular status of the service and using systemctl enable  to put a service in auto-start when system boot. But how can I list all exisiting auto-start services?

Answer (score 8):

For both system and user unit files :

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled && systemctl --user list-unit-files | grep enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi referring to @papey's answer, an option with nicer formatting might be using `systemctl`'s `state` option:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
$ systemctl list-unit-files --user --state=enabled
```